# Update on Windows date IOT hardware acceleration

Tags: windows-iot

Few years ago there was a bunch of posts about choppy video performance with Windows 10 IOT and UWP apps.
This being that Microsoft was working on getting directx or hardware acceleration working with RPI
Is this still an issue and is Microsoft still working on it ?
I thank you in advance.